# What is the challenge orb for?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

There is a (R) Challenge Orb  in my consumables inventory, when I click use it brings me to the quest screen. What is this orb for?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DanmachiMemoriaFreeze/comments/89777b/whats_the_challenge_orb_for/dwpr1go/) users An-Untaken_Username, this is used for events where you will have one hour per day to run the event missions and acquire points:

> You will receive once challenge orb/day. When challenge events are open, you will usually have 2 weeks to collect 400 points to get a duplicate for the featured unit (you won't get the character if you don't already have them, only a duplicate version). If I remember correctly, the first challenge mission in JP featured the normal 4* Aiz.
>
> Each orb gives you 1 hour. Completing - Normal:4-6 points. Hard: 9-11 points. Very hard: 19-21 points.
>
> During large scale events, such as the summer, halloween etc... special challenge missions will appear. Those require 1200 points and will give you a token that allows you to limit break a limited-time character OR supporter (depends on the event).

Here is an example from the Japanese version of the game:

[image]